# Installing Seismic Analysis Code (SAC) On Linux

Tags: ubuntu

I am having some trouble installing SAC onto Ubuntu.
I have downloaded all the necessary files but I just 
don't know how to unzip and untar the files from the 
command prompt. For those of you with experience in SAC,
I really appreciate it if you can give me some directions.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unzip the downloaded file just type command gunzip with file name in terminal.
This will create a tar file then 
to untar this file use the command tar -xvf with tar file name in terminal. To install it, you can take help from readme file in sac directory created after you untar.